# Sending & (and) sign over cURL with JSON

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm sending an array with data over cURL to another server (with PHP).
Code before sending:

```
$array = array('title' => "M&M's milk chocolate");
$data = json_encode($array);
```

and code on the other side

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
```

If there is and (&) sign in array, the $data on other side is empty.

How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: `&` + HTML encoding => `&amp;`

Comment: Show us the actual cURL call construction too, please. I suspect it needs a `urlencode` but that depends how you're passing it to cURL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Html encoding the data should work for you.

```
$array = array('title' => urlencode("M&M's milk chocolate"));
$data = json_encode($array);
```

And on the receiving end:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST);
$title = urldecode($data['title']);
```

Comment: No problem! Feel free to mark my answer as correct!